# SAS - keep name of table being processed

Tags: sas

I'm reading in a number of tables and would like to know the name of the table being processed so I can save it to my output table. Is there an automatic variable or some sort of flag that will help? I'm sure this can be done when reading in a list of CSV files etc. But these are data sets. Something like:

```
%let table_list=one two three;
Data whatever;
  set &table_list;
  table_name = ?????;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the INDSNAME= option on the SET statement.  Look up the details.

INDSNAME=variable

creates and names a variable that stores the name of the SAS data set from which the current observation is read. The stored name can be a data set name or a physical name. The physical name is the name by which the operating environment recognizes the file.

Comment: A link to the documentation can be found [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p00hxg3x8lwivcn1f0e9axziw57y.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) and an example [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p00hxg3x8lwivcn1f0e9axziw57y.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p00fwyxqcqptpcn10ivxt1r470q1).

Answer (score 1):

If you have just created a dataset in a previous proc or datastep, you can use the `&SYSLAST` automatic macro variable to retrieve its name.

If you want to save this as part of the metadata for a downstream data set, rather than storing it in a variable, one option is to assign a label to that dataset, e.g.

```
data input_ds;
  a=1;
  output;
run;

%put &SYSLAST;

data output_ds(label="created from &SYSLAST");
  set input_ds;
  b=1;
run;

%put &SYSLAST;
```

You can also use proc datasets to assign data set labels:

```
/*Modify an existing label*/
proc datasets lib = work;
  modify output_ds(label="New label");
  run;
quit;
```

You can retrieve a data set label using the `attrc` function.